# Continuous Geometric Decay

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that it resembles the function $g:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $g(x) = \beta^x$ (for $0<\beta<1$). The figure below illustrates the function $g$. [image]
How can I define my function $f$ such that it "completes" $g$ in a sense that $f$ intersects all points?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function which contains same values of $g$, then:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\beta^{1/x} &\mbox{when $x = \frac{1}{k} \:\:\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$  } \\ 0  &\mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

If you want a function with that graph none can be created because $f$ and $g$ have different domains.

Comment: Just plain $f(x) = \beta^{1/x}$ works if $\mathbb{N}$ starts at $1$. If the natural numbers start at $0$ just shift.

Comment: thanks! But I wanted to underline the 'critical' points!

Comment: Understood. But I think the OP wanted a continuous interpolation,

Comment: thanks for the replies. Why is it not possible to have a function $f$ with the same graph? Of course the domains are different, but there exist bijections $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R^+$ (for example $\phi(x) = x/(1-x)$). So, with such a bijection, the domain is enlarged such that it includes $\mathbb N$. Isn't possible then to continuously interpolate $g$?

Comment: mmmh I'm not very used with this topic, but maybe you can use bijection from $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ with the function you said and then calling it $y$ use $\beta^y$, so that graph $(y, \beta^y)$ completes the one defined on $\mathbb{N}$?